# Form Navigation in Temenos Quantum Visualizer

Tags: requirejs, temenos-quantum, temenos

How do we navigate between different forms using pure coding only? And should I use the respective Form Controller to write its code?

I can easily implement this with the help of the user interface provided in the IDE. But I am assigned to implement using code